# Selenium by.xpath gives element not clickable exception where as using by.id clicked on the desired element, don't understand why

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.id("input_departureDate_1")); --> worked as expected

where as

WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='departureDate']")); did not work

Please help

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the ID is input_departureDate_1, then using XPath should look like this

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id = 'input_departureDate_1']"));
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for that correction.
I just reverified on the UI and found something like this below. May be is this pattern because of angular application?


<input _ngcontent-c2="" aria-required="true" autocomplete="off" caldefaultdateseparator="false" ngc-calendar="" placeholder="" readonly="true" tabindex="-1" class="form-control inputText calendarInput" id="departureDate">

Comment: Maybe try using a combination of class and id if id alone is giving you trouble. Avoid using . and search the whole page with //*

`WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@class, 'calendarInput')][@id = 'departureDate']"));`